# IC identification on OMRON thermal printer

Tags: identification, wiring

I'm trying to figure out how an OMRON Printer HEM PRT 1-Z operates (see [related question on the Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/135187/111993)) in order to wire it to a Raspberry Pi Pico. Since I couldn't find any "service manual" or schematics diagram online, I'm having a look at the PCB and I'm trying to understand the underlying schematics.
The PCB features various integrated circuits, one of them I couldn't identify.

Here's how it looks like:[image: lousy photography of the unidentified IC]

The shot is a bit blurry so here are the writings on it :

```
1323 HUL
CM29BZUG-3R20
329039
JAPAN
```

(Additionally, any tips on how to determine the USB pinout are welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a Toshiba 8-bit microcontroller. It does not have USB so USB pins do not go to this MCU.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the reference for this microcontroller? I can't find anything for "Toshiba 1323 HUL"...  How weird of it not having USB... The PCB clearly states "USB", and there isn't another microcontroller...

Comment: The chip name is CM29B, short for TMP86CM29B. The photo does not show anything about USB so post a better picture. If the product does have USB, there might be a separate USB chip.

Comment: Thanks again. Now that the chip is identified, I'm posting a new question about the USB matter, with better photos

Comment: Here's the separate question about USB pinout: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/602700/164864