# USB pinout on OMRON thermal printer

Tags: usb, wiring, pinout

I'm trying to figure out how an OMRON Printer HEM PRT 1-Z operates (see [related question on the Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/135187/111993) & [IC identification question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/602695/164864)) in order to wire it to a Raspberry Pi Pico. Since I couldn't find any "service manual" or schematics diagram online, I'm having a look at the PCB and I'm trying to understand the underlying schematics.

The printer doesn't have a standard connector and instead has a proprietary mini-USB-like male connector. The PCB indeed has the cable pinout labelled "USB", but the main microcontroller unit (TMP86CM29B) doesn't have USB support. The printer head is a SII MTP102-16B.

Here are some shots of the PCB:
[image]

Any insight on the USB pinout? How can I proceed to find out? How come the cable is labelled "USB" if the MCU doesn't support USB?

Comment: Well why do you think it is USB? I don't see why they would use something so complex like USB just for printing blood pressure data. Measure the pins with a multimeter. The wire colouring does match USB so they might have just used an existing proprietary miniature connector that pocket cameras of the era have used for USB but for non-USB purposes. Also the images are so blurry it is impossible to see where the "USB" connector connections go.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. Sorry for the bad shots, I don't really have a quality camera at hand & the PCB is quite small. I thought it was USB because the PCB reads "USB" where the wires are soldered

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it follows the standard USB cable coloring and also USB connector pinout.

Like this (From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB))
[image: USB Pinout]

Comment: Thanks. Yet I've been told « there is no standard color coding of USB cable wires »... How could I be sure of the pinout? What about the fact that the MCU doesn't has USB?

Comment: It'd be very unlikely for black not to be ground and red not to be Vbus. As long as those are correct, there is at least no risk of breaking anything. Swapping D+ with D- will not work, but nothing will break. So if it doesn't work, just swap green and white.

Comment: There is a colouring defined in the standard. Another thing is if cable makers actually care about the colouring, as it can't be seen by anyone. And most likely the printer has no USB, just a custom link cable. I suggest to not to try to blindly connect it to any USB device such as PC as it may damage the PC or the printer. Test first with a multimeter.

Comment: @corbin-c I saw in your RPi-question that you tried wiring it up like my suggestion and tried sending random data to it. Did the get enumerated on USB? Can you see the printer with for example `lsusb` on the Pi? If so, it's wired correctly.

Comment: @klas-kenny : I didn't plug it through USB (because I plugged it to a Pico, which has no USB) ; also I didn't want to take the risk of damaging my PC by "blindly connect[ing] it" like Justme pointed out. I connected it through GPIO.

Comment: @corbin-c Oh, right. I'd start by tracing the two middle traces on the PCB, to find where they go on the board. That might give you a clue about what's going on.

Comment: @corbin-c Wait, you connected it to RPi GPIO already and tried to send something? What did you try to send and how? If it is USB then you can't talk USB over GPIO. Also if the printer uses 4.5V supply, it may use 4.5V data on those pins so you may have fried the GPIO pins of your RPi already.

Comment: I used the "VBUS" 40th pin of the Pico, which can provide up to +5V to connect the red wire. I know "you can't talk USB over GPIO". I just sent random 1s & 0s  to see if something happened. (not) surprisingly, nothing did.
The pins don't look fried, I can still use them otherwise.

Comment: @klas-kenny You said on a comment in the other answer, "It'd be very unlikely for black not to be ground and red not to be Vbus." I thought that too! But when changing the lightning plug on a cheap Chinese cable from eBay that had broken off, I was caught off guard when I discovered that whoever built this thing apparently read the USB-A pinout spec backwards, with red and black reversed as well as green and white. Luckily, and surprisingly, this did not damage my new lightning plug chip, nor the phone, it just didn't charge when plugged in, but that may not always be the case!